# Export Excel charts as pictures to PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint, excel-charts

I have in excel workbook with one chart per sheet and multiple sheets, I am trying to export all of the charts as pictures into PowerPoints
The issue is that the current code I have doesn't work
The error with my code:

1. The PowerPoint opens as expected
2. The chart of the active sheet I have selected before running is copied
3. The copied chart is pasted in the PowerPoint
4. the PowerPoint create the next Slide
5. Now the issue the same chart from the same sheet is copied again! I am expecting the code to move to next sheet, select the chart on it, and copy past it in the next slide!

   Sub TEST_ExportChartsToPowerPoint_SingleWorkbook()
   'Declare PowerPoint Object Variables
   Dim pptApp As PowerPoint.Application
   Dim pptPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
   Dim pptSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
   Dim SldIndex As Integer
   'Declare Excel Object Variables
   Dim Chrt As ChartObject
   'Dim Chrt As ChartArea
   Dim WrkSht As Worksheet

   ```
    'Create a new instance of PowerPoint
    Set pptApp = New PowerPoint.Application
        pptApp.Visible = True

    'Create a new Presentation within the PowerPoint Application
    Set pptPres = pptApp.Presentations.Add

    'Create an index handler for the slide creation
    SldIndex = 1

    'Loop through all of the worksheets in the active work book
    For Each WrkSht In Worksheets
        'WrkSht.Select

        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy

        'Create a new slide, set the layout to blank, and paste the chart on the slide
        Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(SldIndex, ppLayoutBlank)
        pptSlide.Shapes.Paste

        'Increment our slide index
        SldIndex = SldIndex + 1

    Next WrkSht
   ```

   End Sub

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: The issue is that the current code I have doesn't work

Comment: I did a quick test and the code worked for me. Please describe exactly what happens:  Do you get a runtime error? Is Powerpoint opened? Is a slide created? Does the Active Workbook has some charts? Have you debugged your code to see where it fails?

Comment: What does it do *instead* of work?  What happens when you run your code?  "My code doesn't work" is not a very useful description of *what actually happens*.

Comment: 1. The PowerPoint opens as expected

2. The chart of the active sheet I have selected before running is copied

3. The copied chart is pasted in the PowerPoint

4. the PowerPoint create the next Slide

Now the issue the same chart from the same sheet is copied again! I am expecting the code to move to next sheet, select the chart on it, and copy past it in the next slide!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how you are trying to reference your charts.  Take a look at your loop:

```
'Loop through all of the worksheets in the active work book
    For Each WrkSht In Worksheets
        'WrkSht.Select
    
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
        ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    
        'Create a new slide, set the layout to blank, and paste the chart on the slide
        Set pptSlide = pptPres.Slides.Add(SldIndex, ppLayoutBlank)
        pptSlide.Shapes.Paste
    
        'Increment our slide index
        SldIndex = SldIndex + 1
    
     Next WrkSht
```

Even though you loop through all `Worksheets`, you only ever refer to the `ActiveChart`.  You need to refer to the chart on the sheet in the loop.  By default, `ActiveChart` references the chart on the active sheet.  This is why the same chart is copied for each slide, because the reference never changes.  So you need to change the reference to the current sheet in the loop.

Change the following lines

```
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select
ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
```

to

```
WrkSht.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartArea.Copy
```

This code properly references the chart.  Also note that you don't need to use the `.Select` method of the `ChartArea`.

Comment: I have tried the code line you suggested and got run time error '1004': Method 'CharObjects' of object '_Worksheet' failed and it highlight the code line you suggested, any help?

Comment: @MohamadAlkhatib "CharObjects" or "ChartObjects"?  Did you misspell in your comment, or in your code?

Comment: The error says ChartObject, sorry I misspell in my comment, I double checked the code syntax it is correct

Comment: That error comes from trying to copy a chart from a worksheet that doesn't have any charts.  Since you are iterating through all worksheets, and trying to copy the first chart on that worksheet, there needs to be at least one chart on each worksheet.

Comment: There is only a chart on the worksheet, because the charts one by one are moved into a new sheet, with nothing in it but a chart

Comment: I think you need to ask a new question.  The code that I suggested will work if you have at least one chart on each work sheet.  It sounds to me like that isn't the case for you here, but I can't be sure.